# Secure url's while using ui router-Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I was experimenting with UI-ROUTER for quite some time when I found that I was able to redirect to the desired page if I manually pasted the end point(url) in the address bar.

See example here:[UI ROUTER BASIC DEMO](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/contacts)

Here in the above example there are two items in the menu bar ie.,`Contacts` and `About`.On clicking each item the state gets changed as well as the url in the address bar.

What if I knew the url in advance and manually added that url end point in the address bar ,it will redirect as expected.I would like to disable this functionality.Has anyone encountered similar issue.Request to share similar experiences.

Comment: That's kind of the point of using URLs as a means of navigation, so you always have a direct deep link to information. You either need access controls, as in programmatically check whether the user is allowed to access a specific screen based on current program state, or you just want to show and hide content without the URL changing.

Comment: If I want to restrict user with access controls,how can I apply it to the state?

Comment: $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
//do smth here
    });

Comment: There you can simply check if the url is restricted and redirect somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use hidden (squash) url parameter:

```
.state("myRoute", {
    url: "/myRoute",
    templateUrl: "...",
    controller: "...",
    params: {
        token: {value: undefined, squash: true}
    },
})
```

User never saw the token, but you can generate one per application bootstrap and use it to verify every state change.

Comment: you mean generate token from the backend service ?

Comment: where you generate the token depend on your client/server configuration, from a backend service is better, but if is only to check the url you can generate it on an angular's service

Comment: I generated the token and I'm saving it in the localStorage

Comment: Failed to instantiate module reactore.common due to:
Error: Invalid params in state 'uom'
    at Object.z.params (http://localhost:50571/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:12299)
    at n (http://localhost:50571/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:6683)
    at q.r [as state] (http://localhost:50571/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:7429)...

Comment: post some code...i've edited my post, remove the :token param from the url

Comment: I have added token at the end of each state